# Triple Integral - Varying Order of Integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to express the triple integral for the volume of the solid enclosed by the surfaces 
$x = 4 - y^2$ and $y + z = 2$ in the first octant in $6$ different ways. I managed to get the correct answer $20/3$ using the orders $dz\,dy\,dx$ and $dx\,dy\,dz$ (answer confirmed  using matlab). What I cant figure out are the limits in the order $dy\,dz\,dx$. My sketch indicates I need to split the integral. I would appreciate help.